# SignalR subscribe response, when response is received component again run ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr

I have a huge problem in my application so I have a signalR service which connect to signalR and to hub in server, on callback function ran component is reload, reloaded i mean that ngOnInit is running again it is very problematic for me because in ngOnInit i have some other action like which can run only once. Some had a similar problem ?

```
@Injectable()
export class SignalRService extends BaseService {

  private connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection;
  private proxy: SignalR.Hub.Proxy;
  private message$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
    success: false,
    error: null
  });

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    super(httpClient, router);
  }

  public connect() {
    if(!this.connection){
      this.connection = $.hubConnection(this.root);
    }

    if(!this.proxy){
      this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('hubName');
    }
    this.proxy.on('CallbackFunctionName', (msg) => {
      this.message$.next(msg);
    });
  }

  public getResponse(){
    return this.message$;
  }
}
```

```
export class Component {

  ngOnInit(): void {

     this._signalRService.connect();
    // other action like retrieve data from server
  }

submitChanges(): void {
      this._signalRService.getResponse().subscribe( (message) => {
        if (message.success) {
           //some action
        } else {
          //error
        }
      });
  }

}
```